# Run Length Encoding in Java - unintended output

Tags: java, loops, compression

I was assigned to do a task for my class in Java. It's basically a run length encoding program that goes through the inputted string and compresses it, (eg: aaaabbb becomes a4b3)

**Process:**

My code goes through every character in the inputted string and checks if the original character is equal to the next character. If its true, *it increments the count and finally concatenates the count and original letter*. If the original letter is not equal to the next character - it starts the count at 1 and initiates a new for loop. If the characters in the for loop are equal to the characters in position *i*, then it increments the count until the next letter is not equal to the previous one. This repeats until all the characters in the input are read.

I attempted writing the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RLE {
    RLE() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.next();
        int count = 0;

        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (input.charAt(0) == c) {
                count++;
                input = input.charAt(0) + Integer.toString(count);
            }

            else {

                count = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

                    if (c == input.charAt(i)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                input = input.concat(c + Integer.toString(count));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(input);

    }
}
```

**Example**

This was my following input: aaabbbccc

*Actual output*: a3b1b2b3c1c2c3

*Intended output*: a3b3c3

Could someone please explain as to what am I doing wrong? I tried redoing the code in a different approach and had no success in doing so. My best guess would be that the original input string was extended and therefore extended the original for loop but this could be wrong too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you shouldn't use variable input for input and output. It makes it difficult to read and maybe produces errors. Than you should check for an empty input. After that you simply need one loop where you pick a character, compare it with the following ones. If it is the same, increase a counter, if not add it to the output with the count, reset the character and the counter and continue. In the end you must check if some rest remained.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RLE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    int count = 0;

    String output = "";
    if (!input.isEmpty()) {
        char actual = input.charAt(0);
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (actual == c) {
                count++;
            } else {
                output += actual + Integer.toString(count);
                actual = c;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            output += actual + Integer.toString(count);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    char c = input.charAt(0);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (!Objects.equals(c, input.charAt(i))) {
            builder.append(c);
            builder.append(count);
            c = input.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
        if (input.length() - 1 == i) {
            builder.append(c);
            builder.append(count);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```